# Power consumption of different computers

Tags: power, power-management

I have an old computer dedicated solely to running a lightweight web server running on Ubuntu.

This is actually quite a powerful computer but I do most of my work off a newer computer.

Recently, I've been wondering if it would be better if I replaced this with a raspberry pi or a chromebook.

I never considered how much I was paying to keep a computer running before but with the limited use of the older computer I wanted to know if I was paying too much from an energy bill standpoint by not replacing it.

How can I go from knowing a computer's specs to knowing it's power consumption to knowing how much I am paying on my energy bill due to this power consumption?

Comment: This seems kinda broad since the actual values depend on what you run. For a laptop, the rating of power brick sounds like a relatively decent abstraction of peak power usage. For a desktop, online voltage calculators exist, tho measuring at the wall sounds like a better idea.

Answer (score 2):

The most accurate way of calculating the individual power consumption of 1 PC is to get an [energy plug meter](http://www.computerworld.com/article/2532730/computer-hardware/review--3-power-plug-meters-help-you-save-money-and-energy.html), this way you can measure your PC:

1. Idle for x many hours
2. High usage (via prime95 or something) for x many hours
3. Casual usage (this will vary from person to person)

Using online calculators can make a decent guess but they'll never be too accurate as there are so many external factors which aren't considered. For example the ambient temperature of the room, if it's higher then the fans have to work harder etc etc.